# Does using pthread_barrier_wait ensures variable visibility?

Tags: c, pthreads, synchronization

In the following pseudo c program:

```
int shared;
pthread_barrier_t b;

// Thread 1
shared = 42;
pthread_barrier_wait(&b);

// Thread 2
pthread_barrier_wait(&b);
int v = shared;
printf("shared = %d\n", v);
```

does the POSIX standard ensures thread 2 will always print 42 ? (I am running this program on X86)
I spent some time reading about memory consistency models (TSO for X86) and cache coherency protocols, and I am wondering if the answer to my question is yes, how does a pthread implementation such as NPTL guarantees that ? If the answer is no, what should I do to ensure 42 is always printed ?

Moreover, I am interested for learning purpose in solutions about manually writing such barrier (a spinning one) with the guaranty that values written before the barrier by thread 1 are always seen by thread 2 after the barrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, As long as you initialize the barrier properly with a count of 2

The functions documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11) act as full memory (and compiler) barriers, meaning memory stores/loads performed before calls to those functions are visible to other threads after those functions. (and memory load/stores are not moved across those calls)

Comment: The sentence "The following functions synchronize memory with respect to other threads: ... pthread_barrier_wait ..." is the one saying that pthread_barrier_wait acts as a full memory barrier ? Can you elaborate on the way pthread implementation is doing this, using an mfence ?

Comment: Yes that is a full memory barrier. No, pthreads is just a specifciation - it doesn't implement anything. A particular implementation would need to do whatever is needed to guarantee that. (e.g. issue an mfence instruction on an x86 processor)

Comment: Sorry I was asking for the NTPL implementation ? I am asking because I am curious to learn the internal of that and was not able to have a clear picture in my mind after spending time reading on the subject. To be more precise, I am not sure an mfence instruction is required on x86 using a TSO memory model

Comment: The atomic compare-and-swap needed to implement the function is already sufficient to provide memory barrier semantics. No "mfence" is needed. (And in general mfence is almost useless on x86 which has strong memory consistency guarantees built-in.

Comment: @R.. many thanks for this comment that confirm what I was thinking. Is the CAS sufficient for barrier semantics because it also "implements" a barrier or because of the TSO memory model ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva You would need a compiler barrier too, for these functions in glibc, that seems to be taken care of since the functions resides in different compilation units than the code(your code) using these functions.

Comment: @nos: The compiler barrier actually comes from the `"memory"` clobber on the `__asm__` block (if you use inline asm) or from the `__sync_*` builtin for CAS (if you use compiler intrinsics). Relying on compilation unit boundaries as a compiler barrier is not valid due to LTO.

Comment: @R.. thanks for your comments. What reading could you please suggest to me to get deeper knowledge about this subject ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva: I would post that as a new question. I don't have any good references to cite right off, but I'm sure some ppl on SO will have them.

Answer (score 1):

Before you create the threads, you should initialize the structure with the the number of threads.

```
#define THREADS 2
pthread_barrier_init(&b, NULL, THREADS)
```

At this point, `pthread` will ensure that neither thread will return from `pthread_barrier_wait(&b);` until they have both reached it, so you should see `42` printed.